# Couchbase cluster's SearchQuery not working on Go client's v2 version

Tags: go, couchbase

What I'm trying to do is performing a search against one of the buckets. I initialized the cluster with the bare minimum configuration, also set the ramsize of FTS and I added the FTS to services. Then I connected to the cluster with the minimum options:

```
cluster, err = gocb.Connect(settings.CouchbaseConnectionString, gocb.ClusterOptions{
    Username: settings.CouchbaseUser,
    Password: settings.CouchbasePassword,
})
```

Then I wanted to do the search as follow (at this point doesn't matter the query):

```
rows, err := cluster.SearchQuery("fts_index", query, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("View query error: %s\n", err)
    return 0
}
```

The result:

```
View query error: failed to get query provider: the cluster does not support cluster-level queries (only Couchbase Server 6.5 and later) and no bucket is open. If an older Couchbase Server version is used, at least one bucket needs to be opened...
```

That's explains what the actual issue is, but when I open a bucket right before the operation, that will throw the following error:

```
View query error: failed to get query provider: not connected to cluster...
```

I debuged the code, and the Query checks for GCCCP polling, so when the bucket's not opened the field of the cluster's clusterClient set to a value, so the GCCCP support can read it, but it's tells that not supported so throws me the first error. After I open the bucket the cluster's clusterClient set to nil and because of this throws me the second error.

Any idea how can I perform a serach?

Versions:

- Couchbase: 6.5.1
- gocb: 2.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a related [issue](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/GOCBC-890), where I have to wait while the code connect to the cluster's bucket properly.

Solution:

```
bucket := cluster.Bucket("bucket")
bucket.WaitUntilReady(30*time.Second, &gocb.WaitUntilReadyOptions{DesiredState: gocb.ClusterStateOnline})
rows, err := cluster.SearchQuery("fts_index", query, nil)
// ...
```

The important part is the `WaitUntilReady`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to open bucket first as described on https://docs.couchbase.com/go-sdk/current/hello-world/start-using-sdk.html

Comment: "but when I open a bucket right before the operation", so I opened, but that throws me an other error.